# Read lines from file and discard "\n" and "\l" trailing characters

Tags: python

If I enter the following code:

```
f = open('/etc/issue', 'r')
out = f.readline()
f.close()
print out
```

I get:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l

>>>
```

if I enter:

```
out = f.readline().strip()
```

I get:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l
>>>
```

(without new line)

But how do I only get:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
```

without "\n \l"?

and what is "\l"?

Comment: `\l` is a line break. See [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/89577/how-to-search-for-line-breaks-tabs-and-special-characters-in-ms-word/)

Comment: Is `f = open('/etc/issue',r')` a typo? You're missing the opening single quotation mark.

Comment: @synchronizer Since *he does get something* it is a typo. I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways.

One would be replace them with empty string:

```
f = open('/etc/issue','r')
out = f.readline()
out = out.replace('\\n', '').replace('\\l', '').strip()
f.close()
print out
```

Or get rid of the last a few characters:

```
out = f.readline()[:-6].strip()
```

Answer (score 3):

`\n` and `\l` are not special characters, they are part of the content of the file `/etc/issue` (see [the manpage for `issue`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/issue.5.html). They have a special meaning that you can check in [the manpage for `agetty`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/agetty.8.html). `\n` means "the name of the machine" and `\l` "the name of the TTY".

If you want to get the release name from the default `/etc/issue` file in Ubuntu (note that this file may be edited to change the appearance of the login terminal), you can simply do something like:

```
out = f.readline().split('\\')[0].strip()
```

A more reliable way of getting the distribution information is using the somewhat obscure `lsb_release` module (APT package `lsb-release`):

```
import lsb_release
release_name = lsb_release.get_distro_information()['DESCRIPTION']
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/issue` is the prelogin message (message printed prior to login prompt). (See Ubuntu man pages for `issue` and for `getty`) and may contain escape sequences such as the two-character `\n` to indicate to another process to add a **nodename** (not newline) and **current_tty_name** (not linefeed) when displayed. That's why you're seeing `\n` and `\l`: they're not single-character escaped newline and linefeed.

To get rid if them you could use `replace()` as suggested, or do similar with a regex, but be mindful of escaping the backslashes. Note that `man getty` lists a dozen or so escape codes.